# JSON data into array with Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a following HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="blogcont">
      <p></p> 
    </div>

    <button class="nvgt" id="prev"  >Previous</button>

    <button class="nvgt" id="next" >Next</button>
```

By clicking on either the Previous or Next button, I want to load the data from a JSON file - articles content. My JSON at the moment looks like below and it is located in separated folder (it is only a test version):

```
var = articles [
    {
        "Title":"test1",
        "Content":"test1",
        "related":"test1"
    },

    {
        "Title":"test2",
        "Content":"test2",
        "related":"test2"
    }
]
```

_(I am not sure if the syntax is correct)

```
 function (){
$ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../Content/test.txt",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function (data){
    $.each(data, function (key, val){

    });
});
```

}
It's supposed to be done via an AJAX request. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Are you wondering how to issue the ajax request?  If using a get - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Post your attempt, if any...

Comment: function (){
    $ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../Content/test.txt",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (data){
        $.each(data, function (key, val){

        });
    });
}

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: I have no idea how to apply it to the next and prev buttons. And also i dont want it in a list.

Comment: Unless you have a _lot_ of data you don't want to load data everytime you click the next and previous buttons. Load all the data in at once and then just cycle through the array of data when the button is clicked.

Comment: JSON should not contain variable declaration

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if JSON, it needs to be like:

```
[
    {
        "Title":"test1",
        "Content":"test1",
        "related":"test1"
    },

    {
        "Title":"test2",
        "Content":"test2",
        "related":"test2"
    }
]
```

Then, do not load data everytime you click on prev, next buttons. Load it once and use it later, as and when you need. Irrespective of that, here are the click/ajax calls:

```
$('#main').on('click', 'button', function(){
  //OR $('#main').on('click', '#prev,#next', function(){
  $ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../Content/test.txt",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, val){
      //Do your stuff here;
    });
  });
});
```